# Error relating to emittery package while running truffle migrate: when I am running truffle migrate following error comes. Can anyone help me on this

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

```
const mixin = emittery_1.default.mixin.bind(emittery_1.default);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
    at Object.call (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\webpack:\Ganache\utils\lib\src\things\promievent.js:23:40)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\webpack:\Ganache\webpack\bootstrap:19:32)
    at Object.call (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\webpack:\Ganache\utils\lib\index.js:33:20)
```

Comment: I found out the version of emittery used by [truffle was 0.4.1] and [ganache was 0.10.0.] Even though ganache was installed inside truffle only it has different version of emittery.